# Type for ObservableCollection<T> to hold generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, dependency-injection

Assume the following classes:

```
public interface ITabViewModel<T> {}

public class FooTabViewModel : ITabViewModel<FooTabViewModel> {}

public class BarTabViewModel : ITabViewModel<BarTabViewModel> {}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<?> _tabs;

    public MainWindowViewModel(
        ITabViewModel<FooTabViewModel> fooTabViewModel
        ITabViewModel<BarTabViewModel> barTabViewModel) 
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<?> Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabs; }
    }
}
```

The `MainWindowViewModel` holds a list of tabs (e.g. workspaces) that will be bound to a view and displayed with XAML.

The issue I'm having is that I don't know what generic type to give to the `ObservableCollection`. I *could* give it a type of object, but I'm not very fond of that idea. I realize I can create `IFooTabViewModel` and `IBarTabViewModel`, however it seems to make much more sense creating one generic interface that every `TabViewModel` can use.

Is there perhaps another design I should be looking at?

Comment: Can you not use 'ITabViewModel' as your generic?

Comment: So you want to be able to put `FooTableViewModel` and `BarTableViewModel` into the same Observable Collection? Why not simply make `ITabViewModel<T>` inherit `ITabViewModel`, and then use `ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>`? You then can ignore the generic type when implementing the interface.

Comment: `ITabViewModel<T>` would seem the obious answer.

Comment: And if you dont want to inherit a new interface like @Tejs proposed you can just use ITabViewModel<object>

Comment: Are those recursive generic implementations I'm seeing?

Comment: @Jondrell: `ITabViewModel<T>` works only if his view model class provides a generic type T. I would go with Tejs answer.

Comment: @Nik: I can't do that because it expect T. Unless you're refering to creating a new interface called `ITabViewModel`.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not sure what a recursive generic implementation is.

Comment: @Mike BoltClock was asking about this line 

`public class FooTabViewModel : ITabViewModel<FooTabViewModel> {}`, which appears to be a recursive definition

Comment: @Chris: Oh. Is that considered a bad thing?

Comment: @Mike it looks unusual but appears to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions which you need to address:

1. What value do you plan to get out of `ITabViewModel<T>` if it doesn't have any members?
2. How do you plan on using the `Tabs` property?

My guess is that `Tabs` exposes a list of view models to the UI so it can create a view-specific representation of a tab for each. In that case, you don't need a common type compile-time because, as the empty `ITabViewModel<T>` points out, they don't have anything in common besides being included in `Tabs`.

If that guess is correct, I would say you can eliminate the `ITabViewModel<T>` type entirely, accept `FooTabViewModel` and `BarTabViewModel` directly in the constructor, and make `Tabs` be of type `ObservableCollection<object>`.

I am basing these decisions on the fact that you are never using the `ITabViewModel<T>` type, and are (apparently) looking for some common interface to group a set of otherwise unrelated classes. That can be cleanly represented by using `object` instead of inventing an abstraction which doesn't abstract anything away.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said you weren't bang on.